# scheme quasiseparated iff covered by affine open subsets, any two of which have intersection also a finite number of affine open subsets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, schemes

It's Vakil's FOAG Exercise 5.1.H. The full statement is:

> 5.1.H. EXERCISE. Show that a scheme $X$ is quasiseparated if and only if there exists a cover of $X$ by affine open subsets, any two of which have intersection also covered by a finite number of affine open subsets.

And the definition of quasiseparated is:

> A topological space is quasiseparated if the intersection of any two quasicompact open subsets is quasicompact.

the ⇒direction of this exercise is easy to show, but the other direction seems much harder. I found a related thread [Quasiseparated if finitely covered by affines in appropriate way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9809/quasiseparated-if-finitely-covered-by-affines-in-appropriate-way) (it adds the quasicompact condition, which is now Exercise 5.1.I in Vakil's FOAG) and mimic the proof in the answer (it's cumbersome, I ask for a solution verification here, but feel free to skip it and give your proof):

> **(Proof for ⇐)** Now suppose $X = \cup_{\alpha \in H} \operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$ and for any two $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$ and $\operatorname{Spec}  A_{\alpha^\prime}$, the intersection $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha \cap \operatorname{Spec}  A_{\alpha^\prime} =\cup_{i \in I_{\alpha,\alpha^\prime}} \operatorname{Spec}  B_i$, i.e., is covered by a finite number of affine open subsets $ \cup_{i \in I_{\alpha,\alpha^\prime}} \operatorname{Spec}  B_i$ ("covered by" here should mean equality). Here $H$ is some index set (maybe not finite) and for all pairs $(\alpha, \alpha^\prime)$, the index set $I_{\alpha,\alpha^\prime}$ is finite.
>
> Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the collection consisting of all distinguished open subsets of all $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$, i.e., $D_i \in \mathcal{B}$ iff there is some $ \operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$ such that $D_i$ is a distinguished open subset in $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is also a base for $X$: any open set is the union of all the intersections of itself with $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$ and each intersection is the union of some elements in $\mathcal{B}$, for the distinguished open subsets forming a base.
>
> And the intersection $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha \cap \operatorname{Spec}  A_{\alpha^\prime} =\cup_{i \in I_{\alpha,\alpha^\prime}} \operatorname{Spec}  B_i$ can be changed to $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha \cap \operatorname{Spec}  A_{\alpha^\prime} =\cup_{i \in I_{\alpha,\alpha^\prime}} D_i$, where $D_i$ is some distinguished open subset in $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha $ or $\operatorname{Spec}  A_{\alpha^\prime}$. And we can assume all $D_i$ are distinguished open subsets of $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$ or $\operatorname{Spec}  A_{\alpha^\prime}$ in the same time.
>
> We prove that following statement first: for every quasicompact open subset $U$ of $X$ and all $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$, the intersection $U \cap \operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$ is quasicompact. (The idea follows from the link above):
>
> Suppose $U = \cup_{\alpha \in H'} \cup_{j \in J_\alpha} D_j$, here $H'$ is a finite subindex of $H$ and all index sets $J_\alpha$ are finite (the finiteness comes from $U$ being a quasicompact subset), and $D_j \subset \operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$ is a distinguished open subset of $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$. Then
>
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> U \cap \operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha &\stackrel{(1)}{=}  (\cup_{\alpha^\prime \in H'} \cup_{j \in J_{\alpha^\prime}} D_j) \cap \operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha\\
> &\stackrel{(2)}{=} \cup_{\alpha^\prime \in H'} \cup_{j \in J_{\alpha^\prime}} (\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha \cap D_j) \\
> &\stackrel{(3)}=\cup_{\alpha^\prime \in H'} \cup_{j \in J_{\alpha^\prime}}\cup_{i \in I_{\alpha,\alpha^\prime}} (D_i\cap D_j)
> \end{aligned}\tag{*}
> $$
>
> In the above equation $(*)$, the equality $(1)$ is from $U = \cup_{\alpha^\prime \in H'} \cup_{j \in J_{\alpha^\prime}} D_j$ where we change the index $\alpha$ to $\alpha^\prime$ for clarity, and assume that $D_j$ is a distinguished open subset in $\operatorname{Spec}  A_{\alpha^\prime}$. The equality $(3)$ is from $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha \cap \operatorname{Spec}  A_{\alpha^\prime} =\cup_{i \in I_{\alpha,\alpha^\prime}} D_i$ and assumes that all $D_i$ is a distinguished open subset in $\operatorname{Spec}  A_{\alpha^\prime}$, as mentioned above earlier.
>
> Now $D_i \cap D_j$ is still a distinguished open subset in $\operatorname{Spec}  A_{\alpha^\prime}$. Hence it’s the spectrum of some localization of $A_{\alpha^\prime}$ and hence quasicompact. Hence $U \cap \operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$ is quasicompact for being finite union of quasicompact space.
>
> Given any two quasicompact open subsets $U, V$ of $X$, $$U \cap V = \cup (U \cap V \cap \operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha) = \cup ((U \cap \operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha) \cap (V \cap \operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha))$$
> Since $U$ and $V$ are both quasicompact, we can assume there is a finite subindex of $\operatorname{Spec}  A_\alpha$ covering $U \cup V$. Then the above equation can be assumed as finite union of quasicompact space, and hence quasicompact.
> ∎

Is this proof correct? Is there any other proof of this? Thank you very much.